# Popup showing exception is activity started

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have a Base class and child class structured Android project. So basically most of the methods in the Base class can be utilized by the Child activities.

Now I created a custom loading type popupwindow whoes method body is in base class so that all the child activities can use the same.

Now the problem creates when I do some initloader call in any of the child activities in onCreate stage, it used to give an exception saying is the activity started.

I Googled a bit and found this procedure:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    cDialog.show();
                }
            });
```

I worked, the popup shows.. But,

Later when the onloadfinishsed occur I close the popupwindow again.

```
public void hideCustomDialog() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (cDialog != null && cDialog.isShowing())
                cDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

It works fine, but now the problem creates when I call loader to fetch some data and its finishes pretty quick lets say. At that moment what happens is the hideloader is getting called earlier since cDialog.show(); is still waiting for the handler post queue.

As a result I'm seeing a infinite dialog.

Any work around ideas?

Comment: what's the error? share the stacktrace

Comment: There is no error, it just calls hideloader before showloader, so the popup never actually closes

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flag to know if the dialog ran `hideCustomDialog()` before run `cDialog.show();`. Example:

Initialize flag to false before running your loader:

```
boolean wasDialogClosed = false;
```

Check if already finish fetching the data:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!wasDialogClosed){
                        cDialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Set flag to true if tried to closed the dialog before showing it:

```
public void hideCustomDialog() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (cDialog != null && cDialog.isShowing()){
                cDialog.dismiss();
            }
            else{
                wasDialogClosed = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT 1**

It's not the perfect scenario, although you could try to delay the process to close the dialog in case is not already created:

```
public void hideCustomDialog() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (cDialog != null && cDialog.isShowing()){
                cDialog.dismiss();
            }
            else{
                Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                //Close the dialog after one sec
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                cDialog.dismiss();

                            }

                        });
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Trying to avoid this procedure, since the method is in my base activity so if there by any chance multiple occurance then this is not good. Any other work around?

Comment: Naa, since the custom loading popup is genrelised for all possible conditions, can't risk it on a delay of 1 sec. Thanks anyways, may be I have to go for the flag thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AsyncTask to carry out similar work.
Just load the dialog in onPreExecute and dismiss it in onPostExecute.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
   //Your Code
 }
 protected void onPreExecute() {
       cDialog.show();
    }
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
   if (cDialog != null && cDialog.isShowing()){
            cDialog.dismiss();
 }
```

}

Comment: Nope, I'm already using loader, I don't need to use a Asynctask furthermore.